# Is the user attention required or not?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing

We are developing 'Work Experience' module. You can see the screen as wireframe attached here.

[image]
[image]

**Scenario:**

1. The User entered information in 1st block.
2. After that, he clicked on '[+ Add Work Experience]' button to enable 2nd block 'Work Experience'(you can see in pic)
3. But he didn't enter anything like just empty(2nd block)

**my question is-**

When I clicked save button, should I show validation errors in 2nd block?
or ignore the 2nd block and save 1st block only?

My thoughts on the user perspective, what is the use to show validation errors in 2nd block as it is empty. With this validations, the user again need to work or spend some time on either fill the fields or delete the 2nd block

My observations in a few applications:

**Mobile**: 
While creating new contact number in mobile, I added multiple fields like home, office, fax, email, email2 ...by clicking on the (+) button of each row. But I entered the number only in the office field. Finally, I tapped the Save button. It saved successfully. When I clicked to edit the number, whatever I clicked before like home, email,.. these are reverted.

**Google Contacts**:
https://contacts.google.com/
I added multiple fields but entered a few fields and pressed save button. Without asking or showing any validation errors it is successfully saved.

The above examples are not mandatory fields. Here my screen has mandatory fields and kind of widgets and overall one save button.

Please share your thoughts and any example if you have seen anywhere.
If I am thinking any wrong direction please let me know your suggestion

Comment: how about the 'add'-button saves any previous information (and highlights possible errors while still opening a second input) while the save button only is active as long as there is unsaved data ? As soon as you enter something new (or have unsaved data because of input-error), the save button becomes active. -- so in your case the save-button would not have been active (error-free first input is saved on pressing 'add', then no input is done)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My viewpoint:

- **Save button on the bottom**. The flow should follow natural behaviour. The user will click on the save button after filling the form and then naturally the action should be there, after form. But if you not confident about this, please add both, on the top and on the bottom.
- You could create **2 stages of verification**:

  1. If any data was filled on the second block of work experience you can show the error of empty field.
  2. If the second block was created but none was filled, ignore.
- A third option is to **show an alert user close to the button** that he clicked that he forgot to fill the second block of work experience. BUT I believe you don't need this because it's just another decision to the user and if they have to take too much decision, he leaves your website/app.

You must understand that the user that will apply for a role will not forget to fill any important information because this could lose his chances.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdGaxESSmeM&t=1988s) is perfect when you are looking for formulary interaction on mobile.

---

**EDITED:**

**While saving, why should not show validation errors in a new block?
I can say the user must close the unwanted block first and then save.**

It's a new task, a new decision and this is bad for conversion rate.

Imagine...

1. The user added 4 work experience block and filled them but accidentally he added a 5th block.
2. He scrolls to top to click on save button
3. We show validation errors on a piece of our page that are not showing OR we scroll to there and force him to delete the block. (Which other alternative whe have for this step?)

I consider this a bad experience because it's too much time and too much decisions and too much thoughts to do somthing that I also considering the inteligent code could do it for me.

Some questions to you thinking and if do you prefer you can answer as a comment:

- Why user really need to delete de add block if is empty? Empty is not the same of none?
- Why scroll page and take the user to the block and show validations error there if we can ask before conclude saving, without scroll, **"You forgot to fill the 5th work experience block. [Ok, proceed] [Cancel and fill]"**

Comment: Agreed: save and cancel at the bottom.

Comment: Consistently we are following main actions buttons at the top in entire application/website. This is only for desktop version.

Comment: @PavanKumar I believe you also should use on desktop. And I hope my answer helped you. If not, please let me know why.

Comment: @BraDev Here is the question. User intentionally or accidentally added a new block.  Instead of ignoring validation 2nd block(2. If the second block was created but none was filled, ignore) while saving, why should not show validation errors in a new block? I can say the user must close the unwanted block first and then save. Please share your comments on this question

Comment: @PavanKumar please have a look on the edited part of the awnser.

Comment: @BraDev I agreed. Thanks for spending the time to elaborate on the thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

I believe when the user clicks on the button save and the second block is empty, don't need validation because it's not a priority for the user the fields empty. If he clicks on the button accidentally he can finish the task and if he needed the second block and forgot, he can edit this information later.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this point - 'If he clicks on the button accidentally he can finish the task and if he needed the second block and forgot, he can edit this information later'?

Comment: Off course, think about this: If a user journey is add one work and he clicks in the wrong button ( in this case a button to add another work) he can complete this journey without a validation because he does not inform anything in the second block.
If a user journey is add another job but he forgot, he can edit your profile and add another work without a problem.
Some case, this validation is not a priority because it does not impact in the journey of the user.